# Finding the cheapest shop which has all the requested list items

Tags: sql

I am currently trying to use pure T-SQL with no additional work done using C# to find the cheapest store match to a list of products.

Finding the cheapest match works well, but my problem is that the found matches (the stores) do not necessarily have all the items in the list.

The tables necessary for this operation are: 
Supermarkets - All available supermarkets.
ListItems - A table connecting item lists and products.
AvailProducts - A table that links between a product and a supermarket. If a row does not exist for a certain product ID and supermarket ID, then it means the supermarket does not have this product at all. This is the table which holds the Price for the product.

My current testing SQL statement is supposed to return up to 5 supermarkets which have the wanted products ordered from the cheapest to the most expensive sum, and it looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 5 AvailProducts.[SuperID], SUM(AvailProducts.[Price]) AS "Price" 
FROM AvailProducts, ListItems, Supermarkets 
WHERE ListItems.[ListID]=3 
AND AvailProducts.[ProductID]=ListItems.[ProductID] 
AND AvailProducts.[SuperID]=Supermarkets.[ID] 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AvailProducts, ListItems WHERE AvailProducts.[ProductID]=ListItems.[ProductID] AND ListItems.[ListID]=3 AND AvailProducts.[SuperID]=)=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ListItems WHERE [ListID]=3)  
GROUP BY AvailProducts.[SuperID] 
ORDER BY SUM(AvailProducts.[Price])
```

The third line from the bottom is supposed to count the number of list items that are available in the supermarket and only return the supermarket's ID if the number of list items and the number of available items in this supermarket equal.

However, this does not work, because I cannot specify the current super market's ID in this statement.

Comment: Try Having clause instead. After Group BY clause add - HAVING count(distinct productId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ListItems WHERE [ListID]=3)

Comment: The HAVING solved it all, thank you!